# Replacing characters in a string Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a data frame that I iterate through and modify as follows:

```
filtered = pd.read_csv(fileloc)  
    
    for index, row in filtered.iterrows(): 
        row["standardUpc"] = row["standardUpc"].replace("['","")
        row["standardUpc"] = row["standardUpc"].replace("']","")
```

This is not working.

Comment: Then you should fix it.  If you need more details, you'l have to provide more.

Comment: Your code does what I personally would expect. So what is your expectation, if not that?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to iterate over the df for this, and instead you should be able to do:

```
filtered['standardUpc'] = filtered['standardUpc'].str.replace("'['","")
filtered['standardUpc'] = filtered['standardUpc'].str.replace("']'","")
```

There are ways to chain the two calls together, but that should be the way that you can do the string replacement.

Comment: Yes, thats my issue. I did not post the question clearly. Essentially I iterate over a data frame and then wrote the changed dataframe to a csv only to find that the changes that I made in the iteration did not save in the csv. It appears as if iterating over a data frame is not a reliable way to change values in the dataframe?

Comment: Specifically I get the error: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead